# Angular JS - How to export Javascript Object to XLS file ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, export, xls

Actually, I've an object in my controller, i just want to export that object as .xls or .csv file.i used a lot of approaches like this:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript" />
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="exportData()">Export</button>
    <br />
    <div id="exportable">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>DoB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.dob | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.exportData = function () {
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
    };

    $scope.items = [{
        name: "John Smith",
        email: "j.smith@example.com",
        dob: "1985-10-10"
    }, {
        name: "Jane Smith",
        email: "jane.smith@example.com",
        dob: "1988-12-22"
    }, {
        name: "Jan Smith",
        email: "jan.smith@example.com",
        dob: "2010-01-02"
    }, {
        name: "Jake Smith",
        email: "jake.smith@exmaple.com",
        dob: "2009-03-21"
    }, {
        name: "Josh Smith",
        email: "josh@example.com",
        dob: "2011-12-12"
    }, {
        name: "Jessie Smith",
        email: "jess@example.com",
        dob: "2004-10-12"
    }]
}
```

but this not works with paginated tables.is there any way to directly export objects (In this example $scope.item ) to file (xls,csv) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can save you data with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript library with XLSX.js library. Here is an example:

First: include two JavaScript libraries into your page:

- alasql.min.js
- xlsx.core.min.js

Second: replace exportData() function in your code with:

```
  $scope.exportData = function () {
      alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[$scope.items]);
  };
```

Third: for CSV files - simply use CSV() function:

```
  alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("john.csv",{headers:true, separator:";"}) FROM ?',[$scope.items]);
```

You can play with [this example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/00nfeq12/).

Comment: This is a great solution, really appreciate the contribution. Do you have any simple solutions for parsing any inner objects and collections as well?

Comment: Yes. You can try SEARCH operator, which is similar to SELECT but it traverse inside JSON object (see here: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Search)

Comment: the plunkr xlsx file has an issue when you try to open it.

Comment: for anyone looking for the xlsx.core dist : https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-xlsx

Answer (score 2):

If you're satisfied with a CSV file, then the [ngCsv](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv) module is the way to go. You don't load elements from the DOM but export an array directly. Here you can see a sample of [ngCsv](http://jsfiddle.net/asafdav/dR6Nb/) in action.

The html:

```
 <h2>Export {{sample}}</h2>
  <div>
      <button type="button" ng-csv="getArray" filename="test.csv">Export</button>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
angular.module('csv', ['ngCsv']);

function Main($scope) {
    $scope.sample = "Sample";
    $scope.getArray = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];                            
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. i used this module. but my goal is Exporting filtered objects directly to `Excel` files.

Comment: Well, you stated in your question that you need to export to an .xls or .csv file. You can always apply a filter to an array (if the .csv still counts).