# Style data and Export it to XLS/CSV/PDF using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, pdf-generation

I have been searching a way to export data to xls/csv/pdf and found many threads talking about this topic:

- [Angular JS - How to export Javascript Object to XLS file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108826/angular-js-how-to-export-javascript-object-to-xls-file)
- [Export to xls using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680768/export-to-xls-using-angularjs)

However, none of these methods support styling data; text color, background color, regular/bold/italic, etc. For example, I wanted to style a header row background of a `xls` file to be gray. Moreover, most of them don't support in Safari/IE9.

Is there any library for exporting these types of data, which support styling data and also support all modern browsers?

Answer (score 0):

For styling you need to use other available API's/`.jar` files

1. Apache POI for Excel
2. IText for PDF

I doubt if any JS file provide support for designing Excel and PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Microsoft Office XML Formats here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)

You can construct a variable with the xml tags, then output it as XLSX.